# XML PATH output one by one using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to group column values by a specific column using `FOR XML PATH('')` in SQL Server.

For example when I pass the `ModuleID` value 1 then output `RoleName : Admin Administrator Super Admin`  which is present is same line.

[image: output]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MEDEIL_SiteRoleModules_SelectOne] 
    @ModuleID int
AS
    SELECT 
        t1.ModuleID, 
        RoleName = (SELECT s1.RoleName AS [data()] 
                    FROM SiteRoleModules t2 
                    INNER JOIN SiteRoles s1 ON t2.RoleID = s1.RoleID 
                    WHERE t2.ModuleID = t1.ModuleID 
                    GROUP BY s1.RoleName 
                    FOR XML PATH('')) 
    FROM
        SiteRoleModules t1 
    WHERE
        ModuleId = @ModuleID 
    GROUP BY 
        ModuleID
```

I need to display one by one

[image: Sql Output]

Comment: Doesn't make sense to use Where ModuleId = 1 with Group since your code will only return one Group.  Remove the Where.

Comment: ok now check it updated code @jdweng

Comment: Is it working?   Does the database have data for Admin, Administrator, and Super Admin?

Comment: yes working fine which is present is same line. @jdweng

Comment: Use String_Agg and make seperator a 0x0A or 0x0D.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

You can just try to use `CHAR(10)` to break lines;

```
SELECT 
    t1.ModuleID, 
    RoleName = (SELECT CHAR(10) + s1.RoleName 
                FROM SiteRoleModules t2 
                INNER JOIN SiteRoles s1 ON t2.RoleID = s1.RoleID 
                WHERE t2.ModuleID = t1.ModuleID 
                GROUP BY s1.RoleName 
                FOR XML PATH('')) 
FROM
    SiteRoleModules t1 
WHERE
    ModuleId = @ModuleID 
GROUP BY 
    ModuleID
```

Comment: Be careful that, management studio still display it same line but if you copy-paste the cell, you will see that are broken the lines.

Comment: I said it made for an example. If you read the cell from your application or from somewhere, the column is got as "Admin\nSuperAdmin" etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `xquery`.. `.node` method

```
select 
           case when row_number() over (partition by a.ModuleID order by a.ModuleID) > 1 then '' else cast(a.ModuleID as varchar) end [ModuleID],
           id.value('.', 'varchar(50)') [RoleName] from
     (
        select ModuleID ,  cast('<m>'+replace(RoleName, space(1), '</m><m>')+'</m>' as xml) RoleName  from <table>
     ) a cross apply RoleName.nodes ('/m') as RoleName(id)
```

Result :

```
ModuleID    RoleName
1           Admin
            Administrator
            Super
            Admin
```

Comment: invalid column name ModuleID and RoleName

Comment: @IvinRaj try to change the table name with your with appropriate column name.

Comment: can you add table name am new in this technology